# Using textures in orthographic projection in OpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm currently programming a primary flight display using Python and OpenGL. As I have zero experience with OpenGL (and little experience with coding in general) I followed a [simple tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/brief-introduction-to-opengl-in-python-with-pyopengl/) giving an introduction to OpenGL for 2D applications. With this basic knowledge, I just started to make everything out of polygons (GL_QUADS) and [some copied code](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CrossPlatformTextOpengl) to draw text. Which gave me this:

[image: Pi2Fly]

The visual result is satisfactory but the performance of ~450 iterations/second is questionable with one core of a Ryzen 1700x at 100% and a GTX1080 at 75% while only running this little program (which is supposed to run on a RaspberryPI 3).

So I want to try out using textures for the whole artificial horizon and inanimate objects like the scale of the speedometer, separation lines or "crosshair".
I've made a .png file that would replace the artificial horizon (see bottom) but I have no idea how to render it. All the tutorials I've found are for C++ and add a lot of complexity to the overall program so I want to ask if there is an "easy" way to implement a movable texture for my application.

Here is a mockup of how I'm currently calculating the position of the horizon and how I draw it (full runnable code at the end):

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import tan, radians

window_width = 800
window_height = 480

class Numbers:
    mp = 0 #vertical middle point of horizon in pixels
    rp = 0 #vertical right point of horizon in pixels
    lp = 0 #vertical left point of horizon in pixels

def calc():

    # mp- (pitch*(pixels/degree))
    Numbers.mp = 240 - (Data.pitch * 8)
    #offset is the vertical distance in pixels from mp
    #offset =tan(roll) * pixels from horizontal middle point of screen to edge of artifical horizon
    offset = tan(radians(Data.roll)) * 300

    Numbers.rp = Numbers.mp - offset
    Numbers.lp = Numbers.mp + offset

def horizon():

    #sky  
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(58/255, 109/255, 171/255)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp)
    glColor3f(0/255, 83/255, 165/255)
    glVertex2f(700, 480) 
    glVertex2f(100, 480)
    glEnd()

    #ground
    glColor3f(150/255, 70/255, 0/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(100, 0)
    glVertex2f(700, 0)
    glColor3f(140/255, 90/255, 0/255)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp)
    glEnd()

    #devider line
    glColor3f(255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp-1)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp-1)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp+1)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp+1)
    glEnd()

def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, window_width, 0.0, window_height, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    #glutFullScreen()
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()  
    iterate()

    calc()
    horizon()

    glutSwapBuffers()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height)
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10)
    wind = glutCreateWindow(b"Pi2Fly")
    glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
    glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
    glutMainLoop()
```

[image: horizon_cut.png]
*The real image goes from 180 to 180 to but that would be too big for SO*

---

full code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import glVertex2f, glColor3f, glBegin, glEnd, GL_QUADS, GL_TRIANGLES
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from time import sleep, perf_counter, time
from math import tan, radians
import pygame

window_width = 800
window_height = 480

pygame.font.init()
font1 = pygame.font.Font (None, 40)
font2 = pygame.font.Font (None, 20)
font3 = pygame.font.Font (None, 25)
font4 = pygame.font.Font (None, 45)

class Numbers:
    mp = 0
    rp = 0
    lp = 0

class Data:
    roll = 20
    pitch = 0
    airspeed = 160

    altitude = 4500

    altitude_last = 0
    altitude_now = 0
    altitude_delta = 0
    altitude_delta_table = 30 * [0]
    time_last = 0
    time_now = 0

    c1 = True
    c2 = True
    c3 = 0

class FPS:   
    c = 0
    fps = 0

def fps():

    FPS.c += 1
    try: FPS.last_clock = FPS.this_clock
    except:FPS.last_clock = perf_counter()
    FPS.this_clock = perf_counter()
    if round(FPS.this_clock) > round(FPS.last_clock):
        FPS.fps = FPS.c
        FPS.c = 0

    color = (255,198,0, 255)
    drawText(5, 9, str(FPS.fps), color, font1)
    drawText(55, 10, "FPS", color, font2)

def get_data():
    #dummy data for artifical horizon

    #pitch
    if Data.pitch < 20 and Data.c1: Data.pitch += 0.03
    if Data.pitch >= 20 and Data.c1: Data.c1 = False
    if Data.pitch < 21 and not Data.c1: Data.pitch = Data.pitch - 0.03
    if Data.pitch < -20: Data.c1 = True

    #roll
    if Data.roll < 20 and Data.c2: Data.roll += 0.02
    if Data.roll >= 20 and Data.c2: Data.c2 = False
    if Data.roll < 21 and not Data.c2: Data.roll = Data.roll - 0.02
    if Data.roll < -20: Data.c2 = True

    #airspeed
    if Data.pitch > 0: Data.airspeed = Data.airspeed - 0.004 * Data.pitch
    elif Data.pitch < 0: Data.airspeed = Data.airspeed + 0.004 * abs(Data.pitch)

    #altitude
    if Data.pitch > 0: Data.altitude = Data.altitude + 0.01 * Data.pitch
    elif Data.pitch < 0: Data.altitude = Data.altitude - 0.01 * abs(Data.pitch)

    #altitude_delta
    Data.time_now = perf_counter()
    if Data.time_now >= Data.time_last + 0.01:
        if Data.c3 == 30: Data.c3 = 0
        Data.time_last = Data.time_now        
        Data.altitude_last = Data.altitude_now
        Data.altitude_now = Data.altitude        
        Data.altitude_delta_table[Data.c3] = Data.altitude_now - Data.altitude_last
        Data.c3 +=1 
    Data.altitude_delta = (sum(Data.altitude_delta_table)/len(Data.altitude_delta_table))

def calc():

    Numbers.mp = 240 - (Data.pitch * 8)
    offset = tan(radians(Data.roll)) * 300
    Numbers.rp = Numbers.mp - offset
    Numbers.lp = Numbers.mp + offset

def frame():

    #frame color = grey
    glColor3f(100/255, 100/255, 100/255)

    #horizon right line
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(99, 0)
    glVertex2f(100, 0)
    glVertex2f(100, window_height)
    glVertex2f(99, window_height)
    glEnd()

    #horizon left line
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(700, 0)
    glVertex2f(701, 0)
    glVertex2f(701, window_height)
    glVertex2f(700, window_height)
    glEnd()

    #right upper divider
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(0, 430)
    glVertex2f(100, 430)
    glVertex2f(100, 431)
    glVertex2f(0, 431)
    glEnd()

    #left upper divider
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(700, 430)
    glVertex2f(800, 430)
    glVertex2f(800, 431)
    glVertex2f(700, 431)
    glEnd()

    #right lower divider
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(0, 50)
    glVertex2f(100, 50)
    glVertex2f(100, 51)
    glVertex2f(0, 51)
    glEnd()

    #left lower divider
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(700, 50)
    glVertex2f(800, 50)
    glVertex2f(800, 51)
    glVertex2f(700, 51)
    glEnd()

def horizon():
    #sky  
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(58/255, 109/255, 171/255)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp)
    glColor3f(0/255, 83/255, 165/255)
    glVertex2f(700, 480) 
    glVertex2f(100, 480)
    glEnd()

    #ground
    glColor3f(150/255, 70/255, 0/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(100, 0)
    glVertex2f(700, 0)
    glColor3f(140/255, 90/255, 0/255)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp)
    glEnd()

    #devider line
    glColor3f(255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp-1)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp-1)
    glVertex2f(700, Numbers.rp+1)
    glVertex2f(100, Numbers.lp+1)
    glEnd()

    #crosshair
    #indicator triangle shadow
    glColor3f(187/255, 107/255, 1/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(400, 230)
    glVertex2f(365, 215)
    glVertex2f(400, 227)
    glVertex2f(435, 215)
    glEnd()
    # indicator triangle
    glColor3f(255/255, 198/255, 0/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(400, 240)
    glVertex2f(365, 215)
    glVertex2f(400, 230)
    glVertex2f(435, 215)
    glEnd()
    #yellow indicator line
    glColor3f(255/255, 198/255, 0/255)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(320, 241)
    glVertex2f(320, 239)
    glVertex2f(350, 239)
    glVertex2f(350, 241)
    glEnd()
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(450, 241)
    glVertex2f(450, 239)
    glVertex2f(480, 239)
    glVertex2f(480, 241)
    glEnd()


    color = (255,  255, 255, 0)
    drawText(110, 10, str("roll: "+str(round(Data.roll))), color, font3)
    drawText(620, 10, str("pitch: "+str(round(Data.pitch))), color, font3)


def speedometer():
    #dial
    ssp = 55 #start spacer
    sp = 27 #spacer
    color = (255,255,255,100)

    drawText(14, ssp+sp*0, "0", color, font3)
    drawText(10, ssp+sp*1, "20", color, font3)
    drawText(10, ssp+sp*2, "40", color, font3)
    drawText(10, ssp+sp*3, "60", color, font3)
    drawText(10, ssp+sp*4, "80", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*5, "100", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*6, "120", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*7, "140", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*8, "160", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*9, "180", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*10, "200", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*11, "220", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*12, "240", color, font3)
    drawText(5, ssp+sp*13, "260", color, font3)

    #green area
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(35/255, 150/255, 29/255)
    glVertex2f(40, 142)
    glVertex2f(99, 142)
    glVertex2f(99, 287)
    glVertex2f(40, 287)
    glEnd()
    #yellow area
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(150/255, 100/255, 27/255)
    glVertex2f(40, 287)
    glVertex2f(99, 287)
    glVertex2f(99, 360)
    glVertex2f(40, 360)
    glEnd()
    #red area
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(151/255, 43/255, 29/255)
    glVertex2f(40, 360)
    glVertex2f(99, 360)
    glVertex2f(99, 374)
    glVertex2f(40, 374)
    glEnd()

    ll=35
    l=15
    w=1
    ssp=64

    glColor3f(255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
    for x in range(0, 14):   
        ind_lines(ll, l, w, ssp+sp*x)

    #knots
    color = (0,  241, 250, 255)
    drawText(60, 435, "kn", color, font4)

def speedometer_indicator():

    ypos = 63 + round(Data.airspeed) * 1.35    
    glColor3f(0/255, 241/255, 250/255)
    ind_lines(40, 59, 3, ypos)
    color = (0,  241, 250, 255)
    drawText(5, 435, str(round(Data.airspeed)), color, font4)

def altimeter():

    color = (0,  241, 250, 255)
    drawText(705, 435, str(round(Data.altitude)), color, font4)
    drawText(784, 435, "m", color, font3)

def variometer():
    color = (0,  241, 250, 255)
    drawText(710, 10, str(round((abs(Data.altitude_delta*10)), 1)), color, font4)
    drawText(765, 10, "m/s", color, font3)
    if Data.altitude_delta*10 > 0:
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glVertex2f(767, 30)
        glVertex2f(793, 30)
        glVertex2f(780, 45)
        glEnd()

    if Data.altitude_delta*10 < 0:
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glVertex2f(765, 45)
        glVertex2f(795, 45)
        glVertex2f(780, 30)
        glEnd()

def ind_lines(ll, l, w, sp): #ll=left limit,l=lenght, w=width, sp=spacer

    #indicator lines
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(ll, sp)
    glVertex2f(ll+l, sp)
    glVertex2f(ll+l, sp+w)
    glVertex2f(ll, sp+w)
    glEnd()

def drawText(xpos, ypos, textString, color, font):

    textSurface = font.render(textString, True, color, (0,0,0,1))
    textData = pygame.image.tostring(textSurface, "RGBA", True)    
    glRasterPos2d(xpos,ypos)
    glDrawPixels(textSurface.get_width(), textSurface.get_height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textData)

def draw_once():
    speedometer()
    frame()

def draw():
    horizon()
    speedometer_indicator()
    altimeter()
    variometer()

def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, window_width, 0.0, window_height, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    #glutFullScreen()
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()  
    iterate()

    try:get_data()
    except Exception as e:print("get_data:\t", e)
    try:calc()
    except Exception as e:print("calc:\t", e)
    try:draw_once()
    except Exception as e:print("draw_once:\t", e)
    try:draw()
    except Exception as e:print("draw:\t", e)
    try:fps()
    except Exception as e:print("fps:\t", e)

    glutSwapBuffers()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height)
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10)
    wind = glutCreateWindow(b"Pi2Fly")
    glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
    glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
    glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pygame to load an texture image:

```py
def LoadTexture(filename):
    image = pygame.image.load(filename)
    datas = pygame.image.tostring(image, 'RGBA')
    texID = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID) 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.get_width(), image.get_height(),
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    return texID
```

Alternatively you can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), to load a texture image, too:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy
```

```py
image = Image.open(filename)
imageData = numpy.array(list(image.getdata()), numpy.uint8)
texID = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.size[0], image.size[1],
             0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData)
# [...]
```

When you want to dare the texture in [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), then you have to:

- set the texture coordinates by [`glTexCoord2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml), before `glVertex`
- bind the texture by [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml)
- enable 2 dimensional textureing by `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`

The following example, draws a quad on the entire viewport and wraps a texture on it. e.g.:

```py
def DrawTexture(texID, x, y, w, h):

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1)

    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(x, y)
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(x, y+h)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(x+w, y+h)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(x+w, y)
    glEnd()

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

Note, if texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).

This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color before you render the texture, to solve your issue:

```cpp
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Likewise you can change the environment mode to `GL_REPLACE`, instead:

```cpp
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

Furthermore, if the texture is partially transparent, you have to enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) before drawing the texture:

```py
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

DrawTexture(....)

glDisable(GL_BLEND)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful.
But I am currently not able to see how you would assign different textures to different quads. Your first code block would be the "loadTexture(filename)" function and the second block would be how you actually use the texture. What would the texture loading function return and how to use that return in the second code block?

Comment: @GittingGud A texture is load on the GPU and is identified by an texture object name (`texID` - in the example above. Of course you create different texture objects and each has its own id. Before drawing a quad you have to bind the proper texture object (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)`)

Comment: That explains it, thanks for the edit.
But I now get a "invalid enumerant" error because of `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)`. Switching `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` with `GL_LINEAR` fixes the error message but the result looks messed up. (And I only get 40FPS)

Comment: @GittingGud You have to explain what you mean by messed up.

Comment: [This is how it looks](https://i.imgur.com/XtbaMY5.jpg), after I only changed the thin grey frame lines drawn from quads with an identical png stretched over the whole viewport. Not only is the background color white instead of the default black but the line width seems randomly changed.

Comment: @GittingGud Enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) when drawing the texture. See the last section of the answer.